# После сборки проекта картинки в формате webp перестают работать

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, webp

Когда запускаю проект локально все нормально работает, а после сборки и заливки на сервер перестает работать, вес картинки почему то намного меньше чем на самом деле и тип text-html [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для создания проекта использовал vue-cli 4

Comment: я думаю, что проблема с сервером, т.к. это он определяет и отдает формат файла. А меньший вес может быть связан с зжатием файла, что тоже делает сервер